# Causal Interpretation of $\beta_1$ with a Dummy explanatory variable

Tags: econometrics, causality

> Suppose you run a regression (over the entire sample) of hourly earnings $Y$ with an intercept and a binary variable $D$, where $D$ takes on a value of $1$ if the individual has a college degree and $0$ otherwise:
>   $$Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1D+U$$
>   with $E(U|D)=0$. Does $\beta_1$ admit a causal interpretation?

My instinct says yes since the zero conditional mean implies zero covariance, which then gives unbiasedness and consistency for $\hat{\beta_1}$. But the solution says otherwise:

> We should not expect $\beta_1$ to admit a causal interpretation here: If $U$ captures all unobserved factors which determine hourly earnings, it should not be the case that $E(U|D)=0$ as $U$ should include some measure of ability which we would expect it to be correlated with $D$. $\beta_1$ simply captures the average difference in hourly earning between grads and non-grads.

Can someone please explain to me how my intuition was wrong?

Comment: Either your quoted question or quotedsolution is mis-stated. They don't speak to each other. If E[U|D] = 0, then $\hat{\beta_1}$ admit causal interpretation. This model is akin to a difference-in-means between D = 0 and D = 1. E[U|D] = 0 means there's no selection bias between the two groups. Now, whether E[U|D] actually holds in your sample is a different question. But if it's assumed to hold, then beta hat has causal interpretation.

Comment: @Michael I agree with you as this was my thought initially. I have edited the quoted solution so that it is verbatim. Does it still make no sense to you (it doesn't to me)?

Comment: No, they are addressing different issues. Issue 1: if exogeneity holds, does beta admit causal interpretation? Issue 2: does exogeneity actually hold for the sample in question?

Comment: What is $U$?  Is it the disturbance term in the population regression model?  Or is it the fitted residual?

Comment: @AdamBailey Disturbance term, I believe